# Can anyone explain How to send survey email to unsubscribed contacts in mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp, unsubscribe, list-unsubscribe

Need to send an survey email to unsubscribed contacts in a automated format through mailchimp. How can we do it? Do we need to sue customer journey?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related.